# Antarctica Exploration

Tags: snow, antarctica

Which parts of Antarctica are unexplored? What about the underwater world of Antarctica? Specifically, what information do we have about it?

What is so interesting about exploring Antarctica when everything is just a massive island of snow?

Would it be worth it/beneficial/possible to place a land-exploring Rover on Antarctica which could be controlled remotely (from a warm base/away from the extreme weathers of Antarctica)? What new discoveries could be achieved?

Comment: Welcome to earthscience.se! As it stands, your question is far, far too broad -- it's not one question, it's half-a-dozen different questions, most of which are general enough that they'd be too broad even if asked inidividually! Please edit your post to focus on a single, specific question which could be answered in a few hundred words -- see the [help center](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for more details. You're welcome to make multiple posts if you have multiple questions, but please don't lump them together like this.

Comment: Did you check Google first? https://www.google.com/search?q=Which+parts+of+Antarctica+are+unexplored%3F&rlz=1CASFJY_enUS951&oq=Which+parts+of+Antarctica+are+unexplored%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160.1437j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on and this question is more of a pop quiz rather than a q&a question.

Comment: "What is so interesting about exploring Antarctica when everything is just a massive island of snow?"

Comment: Which parts of Antarctica are unexplored? What about the underwater world of Antarctica? Specifically, what information do we have about it?
"Which parts of Antarctica are unexplored? What about the underwater world of Antarctica? Specifically, what information do we have about it?"

Comment: 4 questions in one question. :)

Answer (score 3):

What would you have an Antarctic rover do? How would you protect it from falling down a crevasse, some of which are totally obscured? What would you like to be found in Antarctica?

Yes, Antarctica is a large snow and ice covered island. The ice being up to 4500 m thick. The analysis of Antarctic ice cores is allowing scientists to discover the composition of the Earth's atmosphere going back millions of years.

There are nearly 400 sub-glacial lakes in Antarctica, Lake Vostok being the largest. The lake sediments of such lakes have yielded evidence of diverse life forms going back hundreds of thousands of years.

Antarctica has mountain ranges and even 138 volcanoes. Mt Erebus being the one that is best known and is still active.

Much of the exploration of Antarctica involves discovering what is beneath the ice, not so much what is on top of it.